# Revert parts in a Multiresolution sculpt to their original position?

Tags: modifiers, sculpting

Is there a way to selectively "undo" sculpting deformations in a Multiresolution sculpt? Sort of a "bring back the base shape" brush or similar.

Comment: I have some thoughts on how this may be done but nothing that is really straight forward and one-click only.  You should be able to bake a height map and then use this height map to drive a Displace Modifier.  Since the Displace modifier can use Vertex groups, you can paint a mask that will determine which areas are displaced by the baked map and which stay the same as the base mesh.  The setup and learning curve may be more trouble to you than it's worth.  Let me know if you are interested and I will try and come up with a relatively simple walk-through.

Comment: That's fine, thank you. I understand your approach. Thanks for taking the time to write it down!